# Python- Error global name 'id_num' is not defined

Tags: python, nameerror

Here is my code, it has had some major improvements since the last question I had. But I now have a new problem, which cannot be solved by the staticmethod() because it isn't static. Any and all help is appreciated! Thank you!

```
class Student(object):
    num_students = 0
    num_grad_2013 = 0

    def __init__(self, first_name, last_name, id_num, yr_of_grad, counselor):
        self = self
        self.first_name = first_name
        self.last_name = last_name
        self.id_num = id_num
        self.yr_of_grad = yr_of_grad
        self.counselor = counselor
        Student.num_students += 1
        if yr_of_grad == 2013:
            Student.num_grad_2013 += 1

    def __str__(self):
        first_name = self.first_name
        last_name = self.last_name
        id_num = self.id_num
        yr_of_grad = self.yr_of_grad
        counselor = self.counselor
        return "First Name: %s\nLast Name: %s\nID Number: %s\nGraduation Year: %s\nCounselor's Name: %s\n" % (first_name,last_name,id_num,yr_of_grad,counselor)

    def move():
        num_students -= 1
        if yr_of_grad == 12:
            num_grad_2013 -= 1
        print "Student with ID number: %s has moved." % (id_num)

    def grad_early():
        Student.num_students -= 1
        Student.num_grad_2013 -= 1
        print "Student with ID number: %s is graduating early." % (id_num)

    grad_early = staticmethod(grad_early)

    def get_num_students():
        print "There are %s students in this school." % (Student.num_students)

    get_num_students = staticmethod(get_num_students)

    def get_grad_2013():
        print "There are %s students graduating this year." % (Student.num_grad_2013)

    get_grad_2013 = staticmethod(get_grad_2013)

def main():
    print "Creating student Nathan Lindquist" 
    nathan = Student("Nathan", "Lindquist", 11111, 2014, "Iverson")
    print nathan 
    print "Creating student Dylan Schlact" 
    dylan = Student("Dylan", "Schlact", 22222, 2012, "Greene") 
    print dylan 
    print "Creating student Matt Gizzo" 
    matt = Student("Matt", "Gizzo", 33333, 2013, "Connor") 
    print matt 
    # so number of students is 3, one is graduating in 2013 
    Student.get_num_students()
    Student.get_grad_2013()
    # change some things!
    nathan.grad_early()
    print nathan
    matt.move() 
    #matt.grad_early() 
    #print matt 
    # so number of students is 2, one is graduating in 2013 
    Student.get_num_students() 
    Student.get_grad_2013()
    return

main()
```

Here is the full error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\admin\Desktop\Python\student.py", line 71, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:\Users\admin\Desktop\Python\student.py", line 61, in main
    nathan.grad_early()
  File "C:\Users\admin\Desktop\Python\student.py", line 33, in grad_early
    print "Student with ID number: %s is graduating early." % (id_num)
NameError: global name 'id_num' is not defined
```

Comment: Hint: non-static class methods should take a `self` parameter, which can then be used to access attributes of the instance.

Answer (score 2):

All of your methods need to take a first parameter of `self` and you can use that to access instance members. E.g.:

```
def grad_early(self):
        Student.num_students -= 1
        Student.num_grad_2013 -= 1
        print "Student with ID number: %s is graduating early." % (self.id_num)
```